# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, duplicates, build-error

Getting this error while trying to incorporate `SKPSMTPMessage` library. The goal is to send an email in the background as soon as the user inputs his email in registration form. There were some posts which addressed errors like this which suggested to remove duplicate copies of the file, but I don't think that would work in my case since I can't locate the files it is claiming to have duplicates of. Here is the error message I am getting. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks! Sorry I would have attached a pic of the error message but I don't have enough reputation points, apologies if its hard to read.

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/Somedirectory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SomeName-fpfixcxakozxjedlkjmjqhgkpvbh/Build/Intermediates/SomeName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NameLess.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-CAB4E6458C323166.o
    /Users/Somedirectory/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SomeName-fpfixcxakozxjedlkjmjqhgkpvbh/Build/Intermediates/SomeName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SomeName.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-CF88D9F12577867D.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: More info is needed...

Answer (score 0):

It tells you you have more then one `main` file in your code. Look at your code, use the "Find Navigator".